# how to make 2 pull requests from a single branch before the first has been merged on github

Tags: git, github

I'm using github and have a dev-ja branch and have made a Pull Request comparing master to dev-ja.

Say I just changed `Gemfile.lock` in that first commit.

That worked fine. Normally, that has gotten merged in but that was a very small PR and would like to create a second one that is just another commit.

When I look at that commit, I see the changes in Gemfile.lock even if I specify only the most recent commit to dev-ja. In github, how can I specify only to include the most recent commit? Or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify to only include the most recent commit because it will necessarily have the history - which is kinda the point of a version control system.

If you commit to the same branch, then your pull request will be automatically updated.

You could checkout a new branch from before the gem file change and then cherry pick the most recent commit thereby skipping the gem file commit, then open a new pull request from that branch. But I don't think it matters that much in this case, but that's how you *could* do it, but you'd have diverged branches that would inevitably have to be merged or rebased later anyway.